# Adding item to all view menus

Tags: menu, eclipse-rcp

In Eclipse, it is possible to extend to any pop-up menu using the following special location URI:

```
popup:org.eclipse.ui.popup.any
```

Is it possible to do the same for the view menus (the little triangle in each view)? (I am developing an Eclipse RCP application, not extending the IDE. The purpose for this item is to help debugging and testing of the application.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer: no, that is not possible, unless you add the items by hand for all views.

The slightly longer answer: yes, if you

- manually go through the view registry
- create a new `AbstractContributionFactory` with the location URI "menu:<view-id>" and whatever `createContributionItems(...)` you want for each. (Alternatively you can create `AbstractMenuAdditionCacheEntry` or even better `MenuAdditionCacheEntry` - though these are internal and requires a little extra work... The last allows you to have a centrally defined menus extension point that is used for all these additions.)
- add these to the workbench using `IMenuService.addContributionFactory(AbstractContributionFactory factory)` (use `IWorkbenchWindow.getService(IMenuService.class)` to acquire the menu service).

I haven't tested the above recipe, but I have used something very similar in an application...